# operator overloading for manipulators

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I think the following code can be used to create manipulators.

```
#include<iostream> 
ostream & symbol(ostream & output)
{
  return output << "\tRs";
}
```

it is working fine. The following statement

```
  cout << "Total amount: " << 567 << symbol;
```

gives the output

```
 Total amount: 567   Rs
```

But I didn't understand why it is working.
I have the following information about operator overloading in C++.

1. only existing operators can be overloaded. New operators cannot be created.
    But the *symbol* is not existing operator.
2. In the statement (*cout << "Total amount: " << 567 << symbol;*), it seems that *<<* is the overloaded operator and *symbol* is a variable/object. 
   But I didn't declare *symbol* as variable/object.
3. why are they using the return statement (*return output << "\tRs";*)?. I think (*return "\tRs";*) or (*output << "\tRs";*) should work.( I tried but not working :) )

Actually I don't know how the above code is working. Is there anybody to explain the working of the above operator overloading?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are passing the *function* `symbol` to the operator `<<`.  The `<<` will call that function on the current ostream (with the ostream object as parameter), thus achieving the result you see.  (The exact version of `<<` called is: `ostream::operator<< (ostream& ( *pf )(ostream&));` -- see the [reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/) for more info)

The return type is `ostream`, to allow chaining of multiple `<<`'s.  You would not need it technically in your particular case as `<<` has access to the stream, but this is to keep it consistent with the operators (I think).  Of course `<<` requires this return parameter, so you have no choice :)

Comment: do you mean that there exist a predefined overload `operator << (ostream&, ostream&(*)(ostream&))`?

Comment: `operator<< (ostream& ( *pf )(ostream&));` is a member of [`std::ostream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/)

Answer (score 5):

`std::ostream::operator<<` is [overloaded for function pointers of the type `ostream &(*)(ostream &)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt).  The behaviour is simply to call the function on `*this`.

That's how things like `std::hex` work.

Answer (score 1):

There is an existing `operator<<` overload that is a member of `basic_ostream`

```
basic_ostream& operator<<(basic_ostream& (*pf)(basic_ostream&));
```

The signature matches your function (as well as `std::endl`, `std::flush`, etc).